# How do you align 2 lines with 2nd line indented with CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say that I have 2 lines like this.

```
Some Label: First element
            Second element
```

The second line is indented so that it aligns with First element.

This can be done easily with table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Some Label:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First element</td>
    <td>Second element</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I don't want to use  for alignment.

```
<div>
  <span>Some Label:</span>
  First element
</div>
<div>
  Second element
</div>
```

Restriction: The length of Some Label is not known. So I can't use hard coded width.

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: get the width of the label with javascript and set the indent of the second element to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your HTML to something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header">Some Label:</div>
    <div class="labels">
        <div>First element</div>
        <div>Second element</div>
        <div>Third element</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

This CSS will work just fine:

```
.row {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.labels {
    float: right;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ludww/1/**

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't mention whether HTML can be changed. Yes. It can be changed. I think your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.